# Resource based AWS lambda:Permission multiple principals in YAML?

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation

Working on a cloud formation project, and have a resource based policy attached to my lambda; it's something similar to the following in YAML:

```
Mapping:
  AccMap:
    Alpha:
      AWSAcc: 1234567 # aws account numbers
    Beta:
      AWSAcc: 2345678
    Prod:
      AWSAcc: 3456789

PermissionPolicy:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Resource: !Ref LambdaNameHere
    Principal:
      Fn::FindInMap:
        - AccMap
        - !Ref Stage # defined elsewhere
        - AWSAcc
```

I want to grant multiple accounts this permission, for example, multiple accounts in Beta. How would I go about it in YAML? Can I just make `AWSAcc` an array, like this?

```
Mapping:
  Beta:
    AWSAcc:
      - 1234567
      - 2345678
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a list. A [PermissionsPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html) resource's `Principal` property accepts a single string value:

```json
{
  "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
  "Properties" : {
      "Action" : String,
      "EventSourceToken" : String,
      "FunctionName" : String,
      "FunctionUrlAuthType" : String,
      "Principal" : String,
      "PrincipalOrgID" : String,
      "SourceAccount" : String,
      "SourceArn" : String
    }
}
```

As a workaround, add multiple `Permission` resources and look up the principal for each.  `!FindInMap` returns the right `AWSAcc` list for the stage.  `!Select` picks the right principal element from the list:

```yaml
Principal: !Select [ "0", !FindInMap [ AccMap, !Ref Stage, AWSAcc ] ]
```

Change `"0"` to `"1"` for the second principal's `Permission`, and so on.  Note that each stage must have an equal number of principals, or you will get an out of bounds error.

**Edit:**  If the stages have an unequal number of principals, define a [Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html#conditions-section-structure-examples) and apply it to the "extra" `Permission` resources.

Comment: I see. Maybe troublesome, but I only want our beta stage to have multiple AWS accounts (so in this case multiple policies). This would cause multiple duplicate policies on other stages. Are there any good solutions to that? I'm thinking something with `fn::If`, but if there's a more elegant solution that'd be even better.

Comment: @Conanap  Then you would add a Condition that applies if `Stage` equals `Beta`.  The link in the edited answer has an example.